# Is it possible to watch all the events on a Kubernetes cluster using the python API?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

Using the kubernetes Python API< you have to specify the events to watch? Is it possible to watch all events in the cluster

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I am pretty sure that there is a library of Python that already implement this but in my case i implement it using the command: --watch-only

For example:
kubectl get pods --watch-only >  -> will show only the changes in pods.
Creating python process that collect the info from the  will trigger only new changes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are looking for [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/EventsV1beta1Api.md#list_event_for_all_namespaces).

```
import kubernetes as k8s

core_api = k8s.client.CoreV1Api()
watcher = k8s.watch.Watch()
stream = watcher.stream(core_api.list_event_for_all_namespaces, timeout_seconds=5)
for raw_event in stream:
    logging.info("Kubernetes Event: %s %s" % (raw_event['type'],raw_event['object'].metadata.name))
```

I haven't tested the snippet, but it should work.